# Node Deleting But Not Updating

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes, updates

I am making a linked list of nodes contained in an array. Although this might not make sense, even though the nodes are in physical order because they are in an array, they are in logical order by the value of a "link" field.

I created a library in order to utilize a linked list and its related functions. Think of it as the C equivalent of a LinkedList class in Java. Because of this, each node is able to reference any kind of data type through a void pointer.

This is linkedlist.h header file:

```
#define listSize 100

struct Node
{
    union{
        void *dataPtr;
        int countr;
    }dataItem;
    int  link;
};

void initializeList(struct Node[], int);
int  findEmptyNode(struct Node[], int);
void  attachNode(struct Node[], int, int);
void  displayList(struct Node[], int, void(*)(void*));
void insertNode(struct Node[], int, int, int);
int search2Insert(struct Node[], int, int);
void  deleteNode(struct Node[], int, int);
int search2delete(struct Node[], int, int);
int searchList(struct Node[], int, int, int(*)(void*, void*), int);

void initializeList(struct Node LL[], int Head)
{
    LL[Head].link = -5;
    LL[Head].dataItem.countr = 0;
    for (int x = 1; x < listSize; x++)
        LL[x].link = -1;
}

int findEmptyNode(struct Node LL[], int head)
{
    int temp = head;

    while (LL[temp].link != -1)
        temp++;

    return temp;
}


void attachNode(struct Node LL[], int Header, int index)
{
    int temp = Header;

    while (LL[temp].link != -5)
        temp = LL[temp].link;
    LL[index].link = LL[temp].link;
    LL[temp].link = index;

    LL[Header].dataItem.countr++;
}

void displayList(struct Node LL[], int Head, void(*ptr)(void*))
{
    int temp = LL[Head].link;

    while (temp != -5)
    {
        ptr(LL[temp].dataItem.dataPtr);
        temp = LL[temp].link;
    }
}


void insertNode(struct Node LL[], int current, int index, int head)
{
    LL[index].link = LL[current].link;
    LL[current].link = index;
    LL[head].dataItem.countr++;
}

void  deleteNode(struct Node LL[], int Head, int current)
{
    int oldNode = LL[current].link;
    LL[current].link = LL[oldNode].link;
    LL[oldNode].link = -1;

    LL[Head].dataItem.countr--;
}



int searchList(struct Node LL[], int head, int ndex, int(*ptr)(void*, void*), int relation)
{
    int temp = head;
    int nodeRef, found = 0;

    while (LL[temp].link != -5 && found == 0)
    {
        nodeRef = LL[temp].link;

        if (ptr(LL[nodeRef].dataItem.dataPtr, LL[ndex].dataItem.dataPtr) == relation)
            found = 1;
        else
            temp = LL[temp].link;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

I am utilizing this header file to keep a linked list of product structures. The issue that I am having is that my update portion of my application-specific c file isn't working.

As a quick overview I've commented the bellow "update" snippet with what each instruction does

```
if (choice == 4)
{
        newIndex = findEmptyNode(LinkedList, Header);// this retrieves the index of an empty node
        printf("\nUpdate item by searching for it by product code\n");
        getProdCode(&LinkedList[newIndex]);// this fills out a "template" with the product structure that contains the "product code" you're looking for
        current = searchList(LinkedList, Header, newIndex, comparInt, 0);//this takes that new template node and compares it against all other nodes until it finds on with the same product structure and returns the index of that node
        readData(&LinkedList[current]);// this takes that index and fills out the product structure that is attached to the void pointer in that node
}
```

I realize that this is a little abstract so for further reference, this is the c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "linkedlist.h"

#define listSize 100

typedef struct Product{
    int code;//product code – integer
    char name[31];//product name – 30 characters
    int quantity;//quantity on hand – integer
    double cost;//unit cost – double
    double price;//retail price – double(30 % markup from unit cost)
    char loc[7];//location code – 6 characters
} product;


void addFromFile(struct Node[], int);
int Display(struct Node[], int);
void  readData(struct Node*);
void  getProdCode(struct Node*);
void displayData(void *);
int comparInt(void *D1, void *D2);


void main()
{
    struct Node  LinkedList[listSize];
    int  Header = 0;
    int  newIndex, current;
    int  choice;
    void(*stuff)(void *) = displayData;
    int(*item)(void*, void*);

    initializeList(LinkedList, Header);

    //displayList(LinkedList, Header, stuff);

    choice = Display(LinkedList, Header);

    addFromFile(LinkedList, Header);

    while (choice != 0)
    {
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            newIndex = findEmptyNode(LinkedList, Header);
            readData(&LinkedList[newIndex]);
            current = searchList(LinkedList, Header, newIndex, comparInt, 1);
            insertNode(LinkedList, current, newIndex, Header);
        }
        if (choice == 2)
        {
            printf("\n%7s%30s%10s%7.2s%10.2s%10s", "CODE", "NAME", "QUANTITY", "COST", "PRICE", "LOC");
            displayList(LinkedList, Header, stuff);
        }

        if (choice == 3)
        {
            newIndex = findEmptyNode(LinkedList, Header);
            printf("\nDelete item by searching for it by product code\n");
            getProdCode(&LinkedList[newIndex]);
            current = searchList(LinkedList, Header, newIndex, comparInt, 0);
            deleteNode(LinkedList, Header, current);
        }
        if (choice == 4)
        {
            newIndex = findEmptyNode(LinkedList, Header);
            printf("\nUpdate item by searching for it by product code\n");
            getProdCode(&LinkedList[newIndex]);
            current = searchList(LinkedList, Header, newIndex, comparInt, 0);
            readData(&LinkedList[current]);
        }

        if (choice != 1 && choice != 2 && choice != 3 && choice != 4)
        {
            printf("\n\nThe value you entered is not a valid choice\n\tplease try again\n\n");
        }

        choice = Display(LinkedList, Header);
    }

    printf("\n\n\t\tTHE APPLICATION HAS TERMINATED\n\n\n ");

}

int Display(struct Node LL[], int Head)
{
    int choice;

    printf("\n\nProduct Catalog\n");
    //printf("there are %d items in the list\n", LL[Head].dataItem.countr);
    printf("enter a value to indicate what you would like to do\n ");
    printf("a value of zero entered will terminate the application\n");
    printf(" a value of 1 will add an item to the list\n");
    printf(" a value of 2 will display the contents of the list\n");
    printf(" a value of 3 will delete an item from the list\n");
    printf(" a value of 4 will update the item");
    printf(" your choice is >> ");
    /*fflush(stdin);*/
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    return choice;
}


void addFromFile(struct Node LL[], int Head){

    //int i = 0;
    int newIndex;
    int current;
    FILE *fp = fopen("product.txt", "r");
    product *ptr = (product *)malloc(sizeof(struct Product));
    struct Node *node;
    while (EOF != fscanf(fp, "%d %30[^\n] %d %lf %6[^\n]", &(ptr->code), ptr->name, &ptr->quantity, &ptr->cost, &ptr->loc))
    {
        ptr->price = (ptr->cost/0.7);//calculate the cost

        newIndex = findEmptyNode(LL, Head);
        LL[newIndex].dataItem.dataPtr = ptr;


        current = searchList(LL, Head, newIndex, comparInt, 1);
        insertNode(LL, current, newIndex, Head);


        //printf("\n%s\n", ((product*)(node->dataItem.dataPtr))->name);

        ptr = (product *)malloc(sizeof(struct Product));
    }

}


void readData(struct Node *node)
{
    product *ptr = (product *)malloc(sizeof(struct Product));
    printf("Product Code: ");
    scanf("%d", &(ptr->code));

    printf("Name: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]", ptr->name);

    printf("Quantity: ");
    scanf("%d", &(ptr->quantity));

    printf("Cost: ");
    scanf("%lf", &(ptr->cost));

    ptr->price = (ptr->cost/0.7);

    printf("Location: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]", ptr->loc);

    node->dataItem.dataPtr = ptr;
}

void  getProdCode(struct Node *node){
    product *ptr = (product *)malloc(sizeof(struct Product));
    printf("Product Code: ");
    scanf("%d", &(ptr->code));

    node->dataItem.dataPtr = ptr;
}



void displayData(void *ptr)
{
    product* test = (product *)(ptr);
    printf("\n%7d%30s%10d%7.2f%10.2f%10s", test->code, test->name, test->quantity, test->cost, test->price, test->loc);
    //printf("\n\n");

}


int comparInt(void *D1, void *D2)
{
    int temp;

    if (((product*)D1)->code > ((product*)D2)->code)
        temp = 1;
    else
        if (((product*)D1)->code < ((product*)D2)->code)
            temp = -1;
        else
            temp = 0;

    return temp;
}
```

And the referred to "product.txt" file can be [found here](http://textuploader.com/xzxz)

I'm a little confused by this because the same relation that is being searched for in the delete node option is being searched for in the update node option; however, the delete node option works and the update node option doesn't.

Am I overlooking some critical component? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

---

**Disclaimer:** This is compiled in Microsoft Visual Studios 2012. I know there is some discrepancy between gcc and the VS-specific compiler.

Comment: Unrelated : replace your `if` sequences in the main loop by a `switch-case` statement. Cleaner way. You should also comment your library. Parameters aren't always clear.

Comment: There are too many separate problems here. Prompting for user input with `scanf` is quite quick and dirty. For example, typing a number and then a newline will not consume the newline, which might then lead to an empty string being scanned by a aubsequent `%[^\n]` format. Also, getting bad input like "abc" for `%d` will reset the buffer and try to read the same input over and over. Try it when prompting for a choice - you'll get an endless loop. Consider a two-step prompt: `fgets` first, then `sscanf`.

Comment: The index-based linked list has the same problems as a pointer-based list: When you add to an ampty list or delete the first item, the head must be updated. You should therefore pass a pointer to the head index in such cases. Using a union as to keep a count in the dummy tail and as data in regular nodes is asking for touble. And make up your mind whether you use -1 or -5 as sentinel value. -1 looks like the more obvious choice.

Comment: @MOehm -1 and -5 are completely different things. -1 signifies that the element of the list is empty usable space. -5 signifies that the element is the end of the list.

Comment: Aha, didn't realize that. I coud have seen that in `initialzeList`, perhaps. (That function only works properly if `head` is 0.)

Comment: @MOehm true that. that's why it's hard coded into `main()`. I would love to figure out a way to allow for head to change though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that

```
int searchList(struct Node LL[], int head, int ndex, int(*ptr)(void*, void*), int relation)
{
    int temp = head;
    int nodeRef, found = 0;

    while (LL[temp].link != -5 && found == 0)
    {
        nodeRef = LL[temp].link;

        if (ptr(LL[nodeRef].dataItem.dataPtr, LL[ndex].dataItem.dataPtr) == relation)
            found = 1;
        else
            temp = LL[temp].link;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

returned the index of the value before the one that matched. In order get the node that matched I had to refer to the link of the found node. So the option to update became:

```
newIndex = findEmptyNode(LinkedList, Header);
printf("\nDelete item by searching for it by product code\n");
getProdCode(&LinkedList[newIndex]);
current = searchList(LinkedList, Header, newIndex, comparInt, 0);
readData(&LinkedList[LinkedList[current].link]);//this is what changed
```